# Emulating a skype/opus bandwidth-drop tearing/stutter?

Tags: digital, distortion, data-compression

When using skype or other high-compression real-time audio communication (many of which are based on [Opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_%28audio_format%29), I think), and the connection strength weakens, you often hear a digital stutter that involves a sample-and-hold kind of effect like a kind of digital tearing (I've just tried searching for a sample, but I'm having a really hard time finding one - I just heard one on a video conference today, but didn't have it recording at the time..)

Does anyone have any advice on how to emulate an effect like that?

edit: The video conference software was from [Zoom.us](http://zoom.us/feature), I was connected via a laptop, others were connnected via Cisco video conferencing hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Try Speakerphone from Audio Ease. It has a dropped frame simulation you can hear starting from 15:20 in their Youtube video on this product page http://www.audioease.com/Pages/Speakerphone/speakerphone.html

Comment: Wow, that thing's a beast. Seems like the kind of thing you wouldn't be without for film set design, but a bit out of my price range (just hobby music production). I think it's more closely related to the effect at 3:55.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most practical and flexible solution: you don't have to emulate, you can apply manual changes in bandwidth using a tool like [NetBalancer](https://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/) and you can start some heavy downloads, use a speed tester etc to strain the connection

Comment: I thought about something like that - like walking around where the wifi starts to drop out. But yeah, sounds like a lot of work, when it might be emulated relatively easily :P

Comment: Yeah, but it will be the real thing ;-)